# Can I get the "complete" type of a variable in Python?

Tags: python, types

Is there some way of getting the "complete" type of a variable in Python? I know I can do `type(var)` to get the type, but that only gives my the top type, and doesn't work as I want for list, dicts, etc. I don't need it for type checking or anything, only for printing the type.

I know I could write my own function for this, but I wondered if there already is some package or way to do it?

Example:

```py
foo = [1, 2, 3]
print(type(foo))  # Gives '<class 'list'>'
                  # But I would like '<class 'list<int>'>' or something similar
                  # I could accept '<class 'list<int, int, int>'>' or similar
```

Comment: If think you will have to write your own implementation if you want it to work recursively.

Comment: If you include [_type annotations_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), e.g. `foo: list[int] = [1, 2, 3]`, then tools like [MyPy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) can actually check that and you can see the metadata in `__annotations__`.

Comment: `foo.append('bar')` — What now? Did I just change the type of the variable?! That's… weird. This isn't really how types work…

Comment: You need to remember that a list can contain multiple types - e.g., L = [1, 'hello', 1.5]

Comment: It can get even "weirder": `[5, 'foo', ['bar', {5: 'hello'}]]` - because why not.

Comment: Python can't even definitively guess the "complete type" of a list. `[1,2,3]` _could_ be of type `List[Union[str, datetime, Optional[float], int]]`…

Comment: I know that python variables isn't really typed, and that eg. `foo.append('bar')` would change the "complete" type that would be printed. The intent I had for using this was to check the type of a function return, in this case `json.loads` and then be able to add type annotations to the variable I assign the returned value to.

The return value is determined as `Any`, so can't really use the output from mypy either, I don't think.

Comment: You'd be adding type annotation by hand anyway, and you should do that based on the *expected* value of the variables. That's something you should determine from the documentation, or your own reckoning based on working with the data/program. Then mypy can tell you if your code at least appears sound based on the expected types. If you need to actually *validate* the data *at runtime*, you'd rather look into something like JSON Schema and appropriate validator libraries; again setting them up by hand based on your expectations.